# Batch file loop ends after if statement

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which runs other batch files in a loop depending on a variable, however after the first batch file execution, the 'master' batch file also ends.
What am i missing ?

```
:loop
if %variable% == 5 (bat1.bat) else (bat2.bat) 
goto loop
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this even works... You should run batch files from within batch files with 'call file.bat' instead.

Comment: Of course it works, it just never returns from the called batches.

Comment: I used to call _Overlay_ a Batch file executed from another one with no `call` command. The net effect is equivalent to a `goto anotherFile`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are transferring control to the other batch file which means it never comes back to the 'master' one.

You need to use `call` like this

```
:loop
if %variable% == 5 (call bat1.bat) else (call bat2.bat) 
goto loop
```

Which will return control back to the master batch file after the one it calls has finished so it can continue the loop.

Hope this helps

Comment: in the meantime i found that `if %variable% ==5 (cmd /C c:\bat1.bat) else (cmd /C c:\bat2.bat) ` also works, but the call method is much more elegant, Thanks!